# Trouble reading an input

Tags: python, python-2.7

In this program I created it gives me an error when evaluating the input and im not sure why. I am also extremely new to this.

```
def power(maxPower):
    p = eval(input("How much power do you generate?"))
    if p >= 200:
        print "Wow, lots of power"
    elif p < 200 and power > 100:
        print "Not bad"
    else:
        print "Hmm, not so much"
```

Comment: which python version you are using?

Comment: @AhsanulHaque Python 2

Comment: I had python 2 in the tags

Comment: *"gives me an error"* - what error? Why is `maxPower` ignored within the function body? And where have you picked up that `evall(input(...))` is a good idea?!

Comment: What is `maxPower`? why do you need it?

Comment: the function name is just part of the problem I am supposed to do. im just unsure of why i am receiving this error

Answer (score 0):

```
p = eval(input("How much power do you generate?"))
```

`eval` is not needed. Just use:

```
p = input("How much power do you generate?")
```

'eval' needs a `string` or `object`. So, to use `eval`,do:

```
p = eval(raw_input("How much power do you generate?")) #not a good idea
```

You had another typo in your code.

```
elif p < 200 and power > 100:
```

Change this to:

```
elif p < 200 and p > 100:
```

Or,

```
elif 100 < p < 200
```

Best of luck

Comment: I still got the error
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
When i use p = input("How much power do you generate?")

Comment: I am getting no error using 2.7. What are you getting exactly, post the error.

Comment: Using `input` in 2.x is bad practice

Comment: @FrankValdez, are you passing 2 number? It's only the reason to me for this problem.

Comment: I figured it out. I didnt understand how functions worked and I didnt need the 2nd line at all. So sorry guys im just really new